# IPv6 raw socket libraries? Any language

Tags: ipv6

Does anyone know of IPv6 raw socket libraries, and the associated languages? Specifically I am looking to be able to craft any arbitrary IPv6 package and put it on the wire. Does this exist yet?

Comment: I’m not knowledgeable enough to put this into an answer as such (if it helps you, feel free to answer your own question), but libpcap (http://www.tcpdump.org/) is the best way to construct and send specially crafted packets.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by taking a look at [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) and [packETH](http://packeth.sourceforge.net/). If you are open to using [expensive] commercial products, an [IXIA](http://www.ixiacom.com/products/) chasis will probably do most things you'd want to do.

If you just want raw IPv6 sockets, this is [already](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [well](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v53.dmsp1/sok.htm) [supported](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/) in C using any modern operating system. For example, the [ping6](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filewatcher.com%2Fp%2Fiputils-ss990610.tar.gz.64583%2Fiputils%2Fping6.c.html&ei=yUBSTcqjEo66sAOKyvSTBw&usg=AFQjCNGjdnnDHdQy8QQy50hYquJDLKHNQA&sig2=-gtMTlVFLrG28_B9vN-BrA) program in the [iputils](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iputils) Linux package uses raw sockets. It sounds like you want a bit more than this, though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up looking at:

[scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

[racket](http://blog.spoofed.org/)

pcaprub (currently maintained by the metasploit team, and current versions are in the metasploit trunk)

kernel c libraries/headers for osx and linux